# Falta de tradução de pergunta duplicada

Tags: bug, status-pronto, internacionalização

Quando uma pergunta é definida como duplicada, está faltando a tradução.

[image: Duplicada]

Ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

> Essa pergunta já existe e foi respondida aqui:
>   |pergunta| |número de respostas| respostas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested translation overrides are going with the next build (`2014.3.12.1448`).